# Which widget can be used as a root widget (supports Text) in a new route without covering the entire screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a new page route `PopupRoute` and using a `Stack` as the root of the new popup page. It works fine until I add `Text` to its children. Text will have two yellow lines underneath. I tried `Material(child:Stack())` and `Scaffold(child:Stack())`. It can fix the yellow line issue, but it covers the entire screen and make the barrierDismissible **not** work.

Are there any other widgets can solve the Text yellow issues in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your `Text` widget inside a `DefaultTextStyle` widget. A `DefaultTextStyle` widget gets added implicitly by the `Scaffold` or `Material` widget.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(),
  child: Text("This is a test"),
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Altough George's solution works too. But I can put DefaultTextStyle as the root widget. So no need to wrap it in every Text widgets. Just do `DefaultTextStyle(child: Stack())`. Thank a lot. I have upvoted your answer and marked as the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a cleaner solution, but the first thing I thought of is wrapping `Material` inside of `Align` widget.

e.g.

```dart
showDialog(context: context, barrierDismissible: true, builder: (context) {
  return Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, fit: StackFit.loose, children: <Widget>[

    Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
    Align(
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: Text("TEXT"),
      )
    ),

  ]);
});
```

Comment: It works. No need for the Align widget. I was adding Material to the entire Stack which causes it covers the entire screen. If I add it to the Text parent only, it works fine. Thank you very much for this solution. Jordan gave me another answer by using DefaultTextStyle. That works too. I don't know which one I should mark as final answer now... I have upvoted your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I marked Jordan's answer as the final answer. Because I find out I can put DefaultTextStyle as the root widget, such as `DefaultTextStyle(child: Stack())`. Then all text children will work, no need to wrap each text one by one in such case. Just FYI and thank you very much for your answer too. It works as well.

Comment: @sgon00 no problem mate!